# Function not working on server. Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, php-5.3

I'm using this function to check if certain products are in the cart on my woocommerce. This works on my localhost but is giving me a:

> Can't use function return value in write context

on server.

```
function product_is_in_the_cart() {
$ids = array( '139, 358, 359, 360' );

$cart_ids = array();

// Find each product in the cart and add it to the $cart_ids array
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $cart_product = $values['data'];
    $cart_ids[]   = $cart_product->id;
}

// Si uno de los productos introducidos en el array esta, devuelve false
if ( ! empty( array_intersect( $ids, $cart_ids ) ) ) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}}
```

I'm trying to find other methods to do this but i cant find a answer to my problem, I think is because of empty() but how can i do this on other way?

Comment: what about using count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see this is tagged php 5.3

In versions of php before 5.5 [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) will only accept a variable. You will need to assign it first like so:

```
$isEmpty = array_intersect($ids, $cart_ids);

if ( !empty($isEmpty) ) {
...
}
```

Comment: Then your intersection between `$ids` and `$cart_ids` is not empty, you need to look at that next.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your server's PHP.

Check the PHP version on your machine and the server. as mentioned in the  [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), in older version you could only pass the variable.

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables;

Comment: I already know that, thats why i was asking for an alternative method.

Comment: Ideally you should upgrade your PHP version, if it's not possible go with charging a variable with the result of your method

Answer (score 0):

The function is now working like this:

```
function product_is_in_the_cart() {
global $woocommerce;
$items = array( '139, 240, 242, 358, 359, 360' );
// Create array from current cart
$cartitems = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
// Count items in cart
$itemcount = count( $cartitems );
        foreach($cartitems as $cartitem) {
            $productid = $cartitem[product_id];
            if(in_array($productid,$items)) {
                return true;
            } else 
            { 
                return false;
            }
        }
}
```